# Need Help with Custom ModRewrite

Tags: pages, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

How can I correctly send all traffic from:

> **http://my-domain.com/about/case-studies/clientName/**

to

> **http://my-domain.com/about/case-studies/?clientName=$clientName**

(not seen by visitors)

Using mod-rewrite so that when I hit that URL I see the /case-studies/ **page** in Wordpress (in the database) with "Hello $clientName"?

Do I need to create a custom page *file*, or can I get by with my Wordpress **page** in the database?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with WordPress's internal rewrite system by using [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and adding a query var.

```
function wpse47506_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'about/case-studies/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=about/case-studies&clientname=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse47506_rewrites_init' );

function wpse47506_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'clientname';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse47506_query_vars' );
```

This would go in your functions.php file, then visit the permalinks settings page to flush rewrite rules.

You can access the value of the query var in your page template with:

```
<?php echo 'Hello ' . get_query_var('clientname'); ?>
```